# TF compile+install for Python3: cannot import name 'resnet'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, compilation, installation

I am trying to compile Tensorflow from source, because of the AVX issue with the precompiled package since 2018: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19584

I'm running Linux Mint on Fitlet2 MiniPC. "uname -a" says:

```
Linux john-fitlet2 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

"cat /proc/cpuinfo" says: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU J3455 @ 1.50GHz

After compile+install, when I try to import tensorflow in Python3 it fails with:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'resnet'
```

What I did: following https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source but changing pip to pip3, I did the commands shown below. The "bazel build" line took about 24 hours, and seemed to succeed.

```sh
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip
pip3 install -U pip six numpy wheel setuptools mock future>=0.17.1
pip3 install -U keras_applications==1.0.6 --no-deps
pip3 install -U keras_preprocessing==1.0.5 --no-deps

git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
./configure
bazel build --local_ram_resources=2048 --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
./bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
sudo -H pip3 install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

After seeing the problem, based on searching other questions here with "cannot import name resnet" I did:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade keras keras-applications
```

but I still get same error, as shown below.

```py
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import applications
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/applications/resnet.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keras_applications import resnet
ImportError: cannot import name 'resnet'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. There was some still unknown system conflict, maybe due to a previous binary install of TF. I uninstalled my source-built TF, made a virtual environment with 'pipenv' following https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/ and ran:

```
pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

and that was it. All OK if you ignore the FutureWarning noise from numpy:

```
$ python -c 'import warnings; warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=FutureWarning);import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
1.14.0
```